# Oracle WebLogic WLST reference

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I couldn't find complete reference for Oracle *WebLogic Scripting Tool* listing the whole configuration bean (offline) hierarchy and attributes of the beans.

Does such reference guide even exists. I'm trying to explore the configuration tree myself with the WLST console, but am having [technical difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49851140/oracle-weblogic-wlst-backspace-not-working) with the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete mbean reference is available at this [url](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html). All configuration, runtime and security mbeans are described.

Comment: Any idea how could I access `AdminConsoleMBean` in offline mode? I couldn't see it when doing `ls('c')` in the root.